# How do I meditate on PS4?

Tags: ps4, the-witcher-3

I have been trying to meditate on PS4 but it won't work. Can some help me please. I tried to mediate in the middle of the map but it won't work.

Comment: Mediate?? You mean Meditate surely?

Comment: @deutschZuid He could be playing Geralt as a pacifist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are not in combat, on a horse or moving. If not then it must be a mission that you have active so try and complete some missions. I also had this problem but it was soon fixed.